# Extract contents from HTTP request and then get selected contents from it

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

just for learning purpose, i ma playing with page Request and response.I need to know how can i achieve this.What i want to do is to make a HTTP request from windows application and extract some content from it. For example

I am calling `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`
now from response i want to extract all question nodes which is in `<div id="questions">` and format that and then display this in Table. Can some body guide me how to do that. I here that i can do that formating and extracting thingy from regular expression too but i m not sure how.

Thanks in advance
Lura

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it will allow you to get the page directly and query it using XPath, similar to how XmlDocument works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpWebRequest to get Source content of page the as follows.

```
string url = @"http://stackoverflow.com/users";

        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        System.Net.HttpWebResponse  response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader
                (response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));

         XmlDocument rssDoc = new XmlDocument();
         rssDoc.Load(stream);
```

Comment: This will fail if the page content isn't actually in UTF-8; a robust implementation needs to check the `Content-Type` HTTP header or the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">` tag in the body, or auto-detect from the document itself.

Comment: and will fail even harder if the html is not well formed xml.